# does gmake automatically define $(INSTALL)?

Tags: gnu-make

`gmake` doesn't seem to have a value for `$(INSTALL)`. is this supposed to be defined by the user?

`$(CC)` works fine. most sample Makefiles i went over didn't have an explicit definition of `$(INSTALL)`...

if it has to be defined by user, what are best practices (other than aliasing `_PROGRAM` and `_DATA`)? why prefer `install` over `cp`?

###### Makefile

```
helloworld:
        echo 'hello, world' >helloworld

install:
        $(INSTALL) ${HOME}/ helloworld
```

###### log

```
$ make helloworld
$ make install
 /home/<username>/ helloworld
make: /home/kevins/: Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:5: install] Error 127
```

###### version info

> GNU Make 4.3 
> Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default value defined for `INSTALL`.  You can see all the default rules and variables by running:

```
make -p -f/dev/null
```

Whether `install` or `cp` is a better fit depends entirely on your use-case.  `install` does a lot more than `cp`.  But, you can run other commands in addition to `cp` to take care of those things, and `install` is not available on every system.  So, it's what's best for you.

Comment: is there any (commonly used) feature in `install` that cannot be replicated using other tools?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of: this can be seen by the fact that `install` is very often implemented as a shell script :).